# How to create a hard link from within a Python script on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, unix, filesystems, osx-lion

I'm assuming with a call to a UNIX shell, but I was wondering if there are other options from within Python.

Comment: Did you try a search for "python hard link"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would also be that it is a permission problem. For me (OS X 10.7.3), this works:

```
$ ls
slask.py  system.py  system1.gif  system2.gif

$ python
>>> from os import *
>>> link('system2.gif', 'mylink.gif')
>>> exit()

$ ls
mylink.gif  slask.py  system.py  system1.gif  system2.gif
```

And just to make it clear, "Hard links may not normally refer to directories and may not span file systems."

This is because hard linking a directory could create an infinite loop. So directories need to be created using os.mkdir. Then files can be hard linked into that new directory.

Answer (score 1):

`os.link` claims to work on all Unix platforms. Are there any OS X specific issues with it?

Comment: i guess so, i tried it and python gave me this error:

    OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird: How did you try it?  It should work fine on Mac OS X.  Did you try linking to a directory where you have no write permisssion?  (On Mac OS X, the result is `1 (EPERM): Operation not permitted`; the EPERM means you don't have permission to write wherever it was you tried to write.

Comment: Then it would fail with the same arguments in shell. According to the Apple manual `link` can fail with `EPERM` iff the first argument is a directory.